# Impala : argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, aggregate-functions, impala

I have imported a table from MySQL which has 10 million rows to Hive and now performing some operations in Impala to check the functionality and performance. Now I am getting an error `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` when I issue the following query.

```
select count(id) from my_table_name;
```

Is there anything I need to do after importing the data to fix this ? I am intended to use Impala mainly for analytics purpose and so it involves lot of SUM and COUNT functions.

Comment: Which version of Impala are you using ?

Comment: @vgunnu I am using version 2.6

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `refresh` command. 
Here is a reference from Cloudera docs:

> Syntax:
>
> REFRESH [db_name.]table_name
>   Usage notes:
>
> Use the REFRESH statement to load the latest metastore metadata and block location data for a particular table in these scenarios:
>
> After loading new data files into the HDFS data directory for the table. (Once you have set up an ETL pipeline to bring data into Impala on a regular basis, this is typically the most frequent reason why metadata needs to be refreshed.)
>   After issuing ALTER TABLE, INSERT, LOAD DATA, or other table-modifying SQL statement in Hive.